# Why mysql trigger is no working?

Tags: mysql, triggers, hive

Here is trigger.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE x INT;
DECLARE y varchar(50);
DECLARE model varchar(50);
DECLARE Inventory longtext;

SET x = (SELECT `PlayerUID` FROM `cust_spawn` WHERE `PlayerUID`=NEW.PlayerUID);
SET y = (SELECT `Worldspace` FROM `cust_spawn` WHERE `PlayerUID`=NEW.PlayerUID);
SET model = (SELECT `Model` FROM `cust_spawn` WHERE `PlayerUID`=NEW.PlayerUID);
SET Inventory = (SELECT `Inventory` FROM `cust_spawn` WHERE `PlayerUID`=NEW.PlayerUID);
IF NEW.PlayerUID = x THEN
IF NEW.Worldspace != NULL THEN
SET NEW.Worldspace = y;
END IF;
IF Inventory != NULL THEN
SET NEW.Inventory=Inventory;
END IF;
IF model != NULL THEN
SET NEW.Model=model;
END IF;
END IF;
END
```

Here is structures of both tables. cust_spawn http://clip2net.com/s/5SfUtR

and "Destination" table. Character data http://clip2net.com/s/5SfTvg

Comment: Do you care to explain what *not working* means and how you want it to work? What does it suppose to do and doesn't? Do you get any error messages etc? How can we help you if we don't know what it suppose to do? Also post **all the definition** of the trigger. Right now it's uncertain on which table it's defined, what event is used (`BEFORE` or `AFTER`) and what action (`INSERT` or `UPDATE`)...

Comment: Try to narrow down the problem by deleting some portions of the code, and see, whether you get the expected result.